# Why the temp pointer points to 0 instead 3?

Tags: c, ansi-c

Solving an exercise I got stuck in a problem that I was unable to identify. I have some code that needs to store a given pointer on a tempNode. Instead of it, the pointer structure receives int 0, where x is 3.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_NUM; i++) {
        if (y->item == x) {
            printf("y: %d\n", y->item);
            printf("x: %d\n", x);
            tempNode->item == y->item;
            tempNode->next == y->next;
            y = y->next;
            printf("tempNode: %d\n", tempNode->item);
        }

        y = y->next;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler should complain that you’re doing a comparison (`==`) and not an assignment (`=`) needlessly

Comment: Typo: `tempNode->item == y->item;` should use `=`, not `==`. Same with the next line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct answer, thanks to Sami the identified it.

```c
tempNode->item = y->item;
tempNode->next = y->next;
```